# sorting d3js bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i'm using the following example [Interactive Bar Chart I](http://bl.ocks.org/jonahwilliams/2f16643b999ada7b1909)

I tried to sort the bar chart by ascending or descending and i struggled alot, the i found the following sorted example  [Sorted Interactive Bar Chart I](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/f94b60ee252ffb138c7a9d3a5b204872) but it only sort by the first item in the drop drown menu ie TotalPopulation not the rest.

Any help to sort all the items will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can u make a jsfiddle demo for what u hv done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**
First of all, instead of calculating the x-position of each bar on update, use the x-scale instaed. I.e. change

```
.attr("x", function(d, i){
    return (width / data.length) * i ;
})
```

to

```
.attr("x", function(d, i){
    return x(d.State);
})
```

**Step 2**
In your `.on("change"`)-event, you need to resort the data, like you did the first time, but this time use the value in your drop-down. So add

```
data.sort(function(a,b){;return d3.ascending(+a[selection.value], +b[selection.value])});
```

right after

```
selection = document.getElementById("dropdown");
```

**Step 3**
Now you have a `data`-set, which is sorted by the correct property, and you have an `x`-value for each bar that is using the `x`-scale. So the final step is to update the `x`-scale and set the domain using your freshly sorted `data`. So after the sorting which you added above, add:

```
x.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.State;}));
```

**Step 4**
The final thing you need to do is to update the `x-axis` so that the label corresponds to the bar. Do this by adding

```
svg.selectAll("g.x.axis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("font-size", "8px")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );
```

after the code above.

See working example here: http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/f69c4a5c048750f902aa6f925b9f2320

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks Cleared.

Comment: @KhehlaMalakoane since you're new at Stackoverflow, these are some tips: if an answer was useful, accept it. It's a green tick on the left hand side. And once you have enough reputation (15rp), you can also upvote the answer (it's the upward arrow).